# Firefox and Chrome load resources with max-age differently?

Tags: browsers, cache-control

I'm trying to troubleshoot something on the client and I believe it has something to do with the the browser caching requests.

I'm loading the same page on Firefox and Chrome (Canary). When I look in the network tab, I see different behavior.

There server response has a max-age set for cache control. I see that Chrome always loads from (disk cache) if max-age has not been reached. But for Firefox, I'll see it load the resource not from cache once in a while before max-age has been reached.  Also I'm seeing 304 'not modified' in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Also, the behavior from 'Refreshing' a page vs. 'Refreshing Bypass Cache' is not expected.

Can someone help explain what I'm seeing?

Here are some screenshots of the Network tabs...
[image: Firefox Network Panel]
[image: Chrome Canary Network Panel]

According to this [Google article and HTTP-caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)...

> ...the client automatically provides the ETag
>   token in the "If-None-Match" HTTP request header. The server checks
>   the token against the current resource. If the token hasn't changed,
>   the server returns a "304 Not Modified" response, which tells the
>   browser that the response it has in cache hasn't changed and can be
>   renewed....

I've annotated each network line with what my action was that logged that line. (I performed the same sequence in Chrome later...you can see that the max-age is less).

It's curious that in Firefox after the Initial Page Load (when I just refresh the page normally) I see some cached response, some 304's and then an actual non-cached response with a max-age=3600. I expected to see cached responses. Also, if not cached, I expected the max-age to be less than 1490 (max-age of the initial page load).

Then later on after I do a Refresh bypass Cache (SHIFT+CMD+R on Mac)...I curiously see a cached response, then a 200 response with correct max-age=1366. Then further Refresh bypass Cache actions shows cached responses.

I also want to note that each of the actions that I took were less than 30 seconds apart (most of them were less than 5 seconds apart).

**Update**
I found [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/30881/1762) and it explains why the 304's.

> it is because the browser is not sending a If-Modified-Since during
>   the request

This is what the request header looks like for the Firefox 304.

[image: 304 Request Header]

But now I have an additional question...why is the browser not sending the 'If-Modified-Since' and the "If-None-Match" headers all the time when max-age has not been reached?